Method Forward doesn't work after Jumping to X Y Coordinate
I am trying to implement two methods. One to jump to a specific coordinates, the other to draw a line from the current position to the given coordinate.
After using the method lineToXY or moveToXY, I cannot use forward anymore. Somehow it always draws in the wrong direction and way further then expected.

class Turtle {
    constructor(canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.reset();
    }

    reset() {
        this.ctx.reset();
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.angle = 0;
        this.penDown();
        this.color("black");
    }

    resetMoveTo() {
        this.penDown();
        this.color("black");
    }

    penDown() {
        this.isPenDown = true;
    }

    penUp() {
        this.isPenDown = false;
    }

    forward(distance) {
        const radians = (this.angle * Math.PI) / 180;
        const newX = this.x + distance * Math.cos(radians);
        const newY = this.y + distance * Math.sin(radians);

        if (this.isPenDown) {
            this.ctx.beginPath();
            this.ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
            this.ctx.lineTo(newX, newY);
            this.ctx.stroke();
        }

        this.x = newX;
        this.y = newY;
    }

    backward(distance) {
        this.forward(-distance);
    }

    right(degrees) {
        this.angle += degrees;
    }

    left(degrees) {
        this.angle -= degrees;
    }

    color(color) {
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    }

    lineWidth(width) {
        this.ctx.lineWidth = width;
    }

    text(text, font = '10px sans-serif', align = 'center') {
        const radians = (this.angle * Math.PI) / 180 + Math.PI / 2.0;
        this.ctx.save();
        this.ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        this.ctx.rotate(radians);
        this.ctx.font = font;
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.ctx.strokeStyle;
        this.ctx.textAlign = align;
        this.ctx.fillText(text, 0, 0);
        this.ctx.restore();
    }

    moveToXY(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    lineToXY(x, y) {
        if (this.isPenDown) {
            this.ctx.beginPath();
            this.ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
            this.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            this.ctx.stroke();
        }

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

Example:

jshell> /o lvp.java

jshell> Clerk.view();
Open http://localhost:50001 in your browser
$59 ==> LiveView@69379752

jshell> Turtle t = new Turtle(500,500);
t ==> Turtle@1d7acb34

jshell> t.lineToXY(50,50);
$61 ==> Turtle@1d7acb34

jshell> t.forward(10);
$62 ==> Turtle@1d7acb34

Outcome
It should just draw a line to 50,50 and then go forward for 10. But it draws a very long line with a false angle.

What environment are you running this in? What's jshell, clerk and lvp.java?

jshell is the Java shell. lvp is basically the programm which creates a html to make the drawn canvas visible.

Thanks for that--where can I get lvp or some harness to run this? I can probably make my own HTML/canvas but just curious since I've never seen this environment before.

unfortunately the code from the lvp.java is not from me so I cannot share it. It is just the implementation of the canvas as html on a local port

Apparently this is the library used to run things: https://github.com/denkspuren/LiveViewProgramming

I'm not familiar with the environment you're running this in, but it works fine in the browser here. I haven't made any modifications to your code other than to pass a canvas into the turtle constructor rather than 500, 500.


class Turtle {
    constructor(canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.reset();
    }

    reset() {
        this.ctx.reset();
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.angle = 0;
        this.penDown();
        this.color("black");
    }

    resetMoveTo() {
        this.penDown();
        this.color("black");
    }

    penDown() {
        this.isPenDown = true;
    }

    penUp() {
        this.isPenDown = false;
    }

    forward(distance) {
        const radians = (this.angle * Math.PI) / 180;
        const newX = this.x + distance * Math.cos(radians);
        const newY = this.y + distance * Math.sin(radians);

        if (this.isPenDown) {
            this.ctx.beginPath();
            this.ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
            this.ctx.lineTo(newX, newY);
            this.ctx.stroke();
        }

        this.x = newX;
        this.y = newY;
    }

    backward(distance) {
        this.forward(-distance);
    }

    right(degrees) {
        this.angle += degrees;
    }

    left(degrees) {
        this.angle -= degrees;
    }

    color(color) {
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    }

    lineWidth(width) {
        this.ctx.lineWidth = width;
    }

    text(text, font = '10px sans-serif', align = 'center') {
        const radians = (this.angle * Math.PI) / 180 + Math.PI / 2.0;
        this.ctx.save();
        this.ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        this.ctx.rotate(radians);
        this.ctx.font = font;
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.ctx.strokeStyle;
        this.ctx.textAlign = align;
        this.ctx.fillText(text, 0, 0);
        this.ctx.restore();
    }

    moveToXY(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    lineToXY(x, y) {
        if (this.isPenDown) {
            this.ctx.beginPath();
            this.ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
            this.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            this.ctx.stroke();
        }

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

// Code above this line is 100% untouched

// All I've modified (along with the HTML element):
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const t = new Turtle(canvas);
t.lineToXY(50, 50);
t.forward(10);
<canvas width="500" height="500"></canvas>



I think this is the library you're using: https://github.com/denkspuren/LiveViewProgramming. Since it only has 3 stars and things work fine in the browser, I'd avoid this library.
